# Distorted Navigation bar when using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

There is a problem in my navigation bar it is overlapping with my other div element when I started using Bootstrap in it.

I have given color in navigation bar but nothing happen I have pasted my link to the preview of my resume. Also I want to make animation like that when I click in elements of nav bar then it should slide slowly down.

Preview:

[image: preview]

```
<DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <title>MAINPAGE</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="nav.css">
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    </head>
    <body  data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">


                <!---- IMAGE AND HEADER-->
                <header class="container-fluid">
                    <div id="home1" class="navbar">

                            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
                                    <div class="container-fluid">
                                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse collapse in">
                                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav"  >
                                                    <li>
                                                    <a href="#home1" class="active">HOME </a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a href="#resume1">RESUME </a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a href="#thirddiv">SKILLS </a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                            <a href="#career">CAREER </a>
                                                        </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                            <a href="#contactme">CONTACT-ME</a>
                                                    </li>
                            </nav>
                                    </div>  
                    </div>
                </header>


                    <div>
                                <img class="img-responsive blur" src="background.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">
                        <div class="imgtext">
                            <div id="circlediv">
                                <img class="img-responsive img-circle"  src="myresume.jpg" width="200px" height="200px">
                            </div>
                            <div id="circletext">
                                <h1>I AM GAUTAM </h1>
                                    <hr>     <!-- line break -->
                                <h2>Web Developer - Graphic Designer</h2>
                            </div>

                        </div>  
                    </div>

            </div>

            <!-- end first div -->


            <!-- second  div-->
            <div id="resume1" class="resume container-fluid">

                        <div class="heading container-fluid">
                            <h1>RESUME</h1>
                            <hr>
                        </div>
                     <!-- About me-->
                    <div class="abtme container">
                            <h2>About Me:-</h2>
                                <div class="con">
                                    <p>
                                        Name: Gautam Rishi <br>
                                        Birthday: 05/07/1998 <br>
                                        Mobile: 9457444841 <br>
                                        Email: gaut9a8m@gmail.com <br>
                                        Address: R.K. PURAM ,SAHARANPUR-247001.
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                    </div>

            <!--Educational qualification-->
                    <div class="edq">
                            <h2>Academic Circular</h2>
                            <div class="edqcon">
                                <p>
                                        BACHELOR OF ENGINEERING (2015-2019) <br>
                                        Percentage: %    <br>   
                                        10+2 LEVEL  (2013-2014) <br>
                                        Percentage:84.4% <br>                   
                                        10 level  (2011-2012) <br>
                                        Percentage:74.1%      

                                </p>
                            </div>
                    </div>

            </div>
            <!-- end second div-->

            <!-- third div -->

            <div  id="thirddiv" class="third">
                        <div class="tech">
                                <h1>TECHNICAL SKILLS</h1>
                                <hr>
                        </div>

                        <!--- skill bar-->
                        <div class="skill">
                            <div class="html">HTML</div>   <!-- html bar -->
                            <div class="css">CSS</div>      <!-- CSS bar -->
                            <div class="js">JS</div>        <!-- JS bar -->
                            <div class="design">DESIGN</div>        <!-- desiging bar -->
                            <div class="java">JAVA</div>        <!-- java bar -->
                            <div class="c">C</div>      <!-- C bar-->
                            <div class="c2">C++</div>       <!-- C++ bar-->
                            <div class="sql">SQL</div>      <!-- sql bar-->

                        </div>

            </div>

    <!-- end of third div -->

        <!--- fourth div ----->
    [![enter image description here][1]][1]
            <div>
            </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

**Css file:**

```
html,body,.container{
    height:100%
    width:100%;
    margin:0px 0px;
        font-family: Montserrat,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}


/* first div css*/

.firstdiv{
margin-top:0px;
display:inline-block;
width:100%;
}

.navbar{
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#2c3e50;
    text-align:center;
    padding:20;
}
.navbar nav ul li{
    display:inline;
border-right: 1px solid #2c3e50;


}
.navbar nav ul li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
.navbar nav ul li a{
    font-size:30px;
text-decoration:none;
color:#ecf0f1;

margin-left:10px;
transition: all .2s;
}
.navbar nav ul li a:hover{
background-color:#3498db;
}

header{

}
.bkimg{
    margin-top:0px;
    position:relative;
}
.imgtext{
    position:absolute;
    right:25%;
    top:25%;
    left:25%;
    bottom:25%;
}
.img-circle{
    border:0px solid black;
    border-radius:50%;
    margin: 20% auto;
}

.blur{
-webkit-filter: blur(2px);      
}
#circletext{
            margin-top: -107px;
    text-align: center;
}

/* second div css*/


.resume{
position:relative;
margin-top:-50px;
width:100%;
height:80%;
background-color:#2980b9;
}
.resume .heading{
background-color:#2c3e50;
margin-top:-30px;
margin-left:-20px;
margin-right:-20px;
}
.resume .heading h1{

        color:white;
text-align:center;
font-size: 70px;
padding-top:30px;
}
.abtme{
    width:30%;
height:50%;
    position:absolute;
    top:40%;
    left:20%;
bottom:inherit;
background-color:#3498db;
 box-shadow: 5px 0px white;
}
.abtme h2{
        text-align:center;
        color:white;
        text-decoration:underline;
        font-size:40px;
    padding:10px 10px;
}
.abtme p{
    padding: 10px 10px;
    text-align:left;
color:white;
font:30;
}

.edq{
    width:30%;
height:50%;
    position:absolute;
    top:40%;
    right:20%;
bottom:inherit;
background-color:#3498db;

}
.edq h2{
        text-align:center;
        color:white;
        text-decoration:underline;
        font-size:40px;
padding:10px 10px;

}
.edq p{
    padding: 10px 10px;
    text-align:left;
color:white;
font:30;
}


/*css third div  */
.third{
        position:absolute;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        background-color:#2980b9;
}
.tech
{
    background-color:#2c3e50;
    margin-top:-40px;
}
.third div h1{
        color:white;
text-align:center;
font-size: 60px;
padding-top:30px;

}

.skill{
    position:absolute;
    top:30%;
    left:10%;
    right:10%;
    bottom:5%;
    background-color: #3498db;
    color:white;
}
.skill .html{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-left:15%;
    display:inline;
    width:100px;
    height:55px;
    border: 5px solid white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top-color:RED;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:50px;

}

.skill .css{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 10%;
    left:35%;
    display:inline;
    width:100px;
    height:55px;
    border: 5px solid white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top-color:RED;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:50px;
}

.skill .js{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-left:55%;
    display:inline;
    width:100px;
    height:55px;
    border: 5px solid white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top-color:RED;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:50px;
}

.skill .design{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-left:75%;
    display:inline;
    width:100px;
    height:55px;
    border: 5px solid white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top-color:RED;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:50px;
}


.skill .java{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 25%;
    margin-left:15%;
    display:inline;
    width:100px;
    height:55px;
    border: 5px solid white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top-color:RED;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:50px;
}


.skill .c{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 25%;
    margin-left:35%;
    display:inline;
    width:100px;
    height:55px;
    border: 5px solid white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top-color:RED;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:50px;
}

.skill .c2{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 25%;
    margin-left:55%;
    display:inline;
    width:100px;
    height:55px;
    border: 5px solid white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top-color:RED;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:50px;
}

.skill .sql{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 25%;
    margin-left:75%;
    display:inline;
    width:100px;
    height:55px;
    border: 5px solid white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top-color:RED;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:50px;
}


/* ---------------------------    media code for different resolution of screen browser responsive -----------    */

@media(max-width:540px){
        .first,.third,.resume{
            width:100%;
            }
        .skills,.abtme,.edq{
            width:50%;

        }
        .html,.css,.js,.java,.c,.design,.c2,.sql{
            width:50%;
            height:50%;

        }
}
```

Comment: Add CSS code too, If possible add working snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this two lines in your code, as you missing js file in your code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_inverse&stacked=h check this url

Comment: check this url as well "https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp" you will get more example for learn and implement.